# Can't route specified site traffic to direct WiFi connection, to avoid VPN

Tags: macos, network, catalina, vpn

macOS Catalina 10.15.2

WiFi on en0 (MAC xx:xx:xx:xx:85:80)

VPN — Wireguard CLI (utun2)

I have a permanent VPN connection and all traffic is going through it. But I need to route traffic for music.yandex.ru (213.180.204.186) to the Wi-Fi connection.

I used the command `route add -host music.yandex.ru -interface en0` to do it. The resulting routing table (`netstat -nr`) is below:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
0/1                utun2              USc          utun2
default            192.168.43.63      UGSc           en0
10.217.47.164      10.217.47.164      UH           utun2
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0
128.0/1            utun2              USc          utun2
169.254            link#5             UCS            en0      !
190.2.141.162      192.168.43.63      UGHS           en0
192.168.43         link#5             UCS            en0      !
192.168.43.42/32   link#5             UCS            en0      !
192.168.43.63/32   link#5             UCS            en0      !
192.168.43.63      0:a:f5:12:f9:98    UHLWIir        en0   1197
213.180.204.186    xx:xx:xx:xx:85:80  UHLS           en0
224.0.0/4          link#5             UmCS           en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#5             UCS            en0      !
```

But after adding the route for music.yandex.ru it becomes unreacheable. I don't get any ping returns.

Then, I used direct forward to my gateway IP by `route add -host music.yandex.ru 192.168.43.63`

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
0/1                utun2              USc          utun2
default            192.168.43.63      UGSc           en0
10.217.47.164      10.217.47.164      UH           utun2
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0
128.0/1            utun2              USc          utun2
169.254            link#5             UCS            en0      !
190.2.141.162      192.168.43.63      UGHS           en0
192.168.43         link#5             UCS            en0      !
192.168.43.42/32   link#5             UCS            en0      !
192.168.43.63/32   link#5             UCS            en0      !
192.168.43.63      0:a:f5:12:f9:98    UHLWIir        en0   1200
213.180.204.186    192.168.43.63      UGHS           en0
224.0.0/4          link#5             UmCS           en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#5             UCS            en0      !
```

And everything works as I want. But I need to use the network interface instead of the gateway IP, because it usually changes from time to time.

How can I set proper redirection?

Comment: What kind of device is the gateway (192.168.43.63)? In a soho environment this normally is a router and its internal (non-routeable in the WAN because of the private IP-range) IP never changes (except intentionally).

Comment: Gateway is a usual home WiFi router. The reason of changing gateway IP — I often connect to different networks outside my home. That’s why I don't want to use gateway IP, because I should manually change it each time in cafés.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of the `-interface` option is faulty. As the router's man page `man router`describes:

> If the destination is directly reachable via an interface requiring no
>   intermediary system to act as a gateway, the -interface modifier should
>   be specified; the gateway given is the address of this host on the common
>   network, indicating the interface to be used for transmission.

The host *music.yandex.ru (213.180.204.186)* is no destination directly reachable via en0. It requires at least one intermediary system (your Wi-Fi router) to reach this host.

Compare this with your router:

```
192.168.43.63      0:a:f5:12:f9:98    UHLWIir        en0   1200
```

The router's Wi-Fi interface is "directly connected" to your Mac's Wi-Fi interface. 0:a:f5:12:f9:98 is your router's MAC-address (some Airgo/Qualcomm device).

Additional background: The MAC address is an address of a node on the data link layer (layer 2). Layer 2 has no routing capability. Routing is done on the network layer (layer 3) - nodes of the network layer have IP addresses!

---

If your VPN app doesn't provide the feature to route single IP-addresses to the system's default gateway (the IP address of your Wi-Fi router), you indeed have to create static routes.

To deal with changing networks (and thus changing default gateways) simply create different locations in System Preferences > Network > Location.

Comment: Yep, using Network > Location looks like a workaround. Thx